Let's get critical: Apr 2015 Site Self-Evaluation
We all love LEGO® Answers, but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.
The Site Self-Evaluation review queue is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.
Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? Post an answer below to share your thoughts and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Final Results

Are BanBao bricks compatible with Lego?

Net Score: 5 (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)


Where are the electric pieces for 42029?

Net Score: 4 (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)


Lego Escher structures

Net Score: 4 (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)


What logos appear on Duplo brick studs?

Net Score: 3 (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)


Old sets, new bricks

Net Score: 2 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)


EV3 controlled by 8879 speed control through IR sensor

Net Score: 2 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)


Quick way to inventory parts

Net Score: 1 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)


Why doesn't lego make many 2x2x4 Pieces?

Net Score: 1 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)


How can I use bluetooth on my phone to run a program on the EV3 brick?

Net Score: -1 (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)


Mindstorm EV3 no longer recognises SD card

Net Score: -2 (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 2)


I'm surprised that there are not more questions about building problems.  
It's nice to see many people taking a go at solving a specific building problem.  You can see all the different approaches and building styles in the answers.  Here are some examples that already exist:

How do I build a curved wall?
Brick-built alternative to "Door 2 x 5 x 5 Swivel, Bracket Base"
Any way to make this setup "tighter"?
What elements do I need to create a smooth multi cheese slope ramp?


Some times you just get stuck.  It's often great to see what other people can do to help you get past road blocks, but I don't know if this is a great site for that kind of discussion, since there's rarely a single correct answer.  Is that the kind of thing we want on the site?  The OP can mark the solution they went with as the answer, but all the submitted answers might be sufficient, or be more applicable to other people.
That said, it is nice to see the solutions that people come up with. So I'm torn.

@Grandpappy It seems like this may be what we want. I think that we want more questions that open themselves to multiple "correct" answers so that we can actually vote on and discuss the best ones. I feel like we too often have questions with one or two answers, and then that's all we get. Compare this to something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179123 where there are many answers with slightly different ways to essentially do the same thing. That seems to add a lot of value.

@Grandpappy I am a software developer by trade and I have used StackOverflow for years.  In programming there is as many solution to a problem as there are programmers trying to solve it.  Most of the time a majority will agree what could be the best solution but sharing all those solutions and seeing all the different approaches is a an amazing part of what makes Stack Exchange great. I see LEGO building the same way and I would love to see people fearlessly present all their expertise, experiences and creativity through this site.

You both make great points, and I agree.  Once the stackoverflow method of many answer was brought up, I was completely sold.  I'm also a developer, and having a good way to see the breadth of answers is often helpful.
